# Media library orphans

Tags: post-meta, media-library

I have this conditional statement that checks if an image has been added to a custom post type and if it hasn't it inserts a default image.

```
if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'team_page_custom_image', true ) ) {

echo wp_get_attachment_image($post_meta_data['team_page_custom_image'][0], 'medium');  
    }  
    else {
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/img/team-logo.png" />';
    }
```

It seems works fine except when an image is chosen and then deleted from the media library it leaves a blank spot as there is still a meta value in the database for the post-meta.

I know I can just delete them from the database but is there a function somewhere to take care of orphans from media library deletions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can be solved at run-time. [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) says:

> Returns an HTML image element representing an attachment file, if there is any, otherwise an empty string.

So, if the post meta is set, but an empty string is given, we should delete the post meta.

```
$default = '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/team-logo.png" />';

if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'team_page_custom_image', true ) ) 
{
    $get_img = wp_get_attachment_image( $post_meta_data['team_page_custom_image'][0], 'medium' );  

    if( !emtpy( $get_img ) )
    {
        echo $get_img;
    }
    else
    {
        delete_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'team_page_custom_image' );
        echo $default;
    }
}  
else 
{
    echo $default;
}
```

Or you can create a routine with `get_posts()` (in some hook or Settings API) to iterate through all posts and check/delete orphans.